# Getting the Average

Tags: java

I needed to consider die class and implement the measurable interface.
Then I had to generate dice, cast & add them to the first implementation of the DataSet class and then display the average.  My problem is getting the average.  When I tried having my code in my tester pull it from the DataSet class, but it would get an error.  VS Code underlines the **"ds.add(d);"** and when I do it's recommended fix that does mess a bunch of stuff up It adds the implement measurable to the entire class and then the `getMeasure()` method.  It only returns an average of 0 and I think that is because the `getMeasure()` method is set to return 0 and I can't figure out how to fix it.  Please Help.

Thanks!!

Die class and tester

```
import java.util.Random;

public class P11_1 implements Measurable 
{
    private Random generator;
    private int sides;

    public P11_1(int s)
    {
        sides = s;
        generator = new Random();
    }

    public int cast()
    {
        return 1 + generator.nextInt(sides);
    }

    public double getMeasure() {
        return 0;
}



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final int TRIES = 10;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        P11_1 d = new P11_1(6);

        for(int i = 1; i <= TRIES; i++)
        {
            int n = d.cast();
            ds.add(d);
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + ds.getAverage());
    }

}
```

DataSet

```
public class DataSet 
{
    private double sum;
    private int count;
    private Measurable maximum;

    public DataSet()
    {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        maximum = null;
    }

    public void add(Measurable d) {
        sum = sum + d.getMeasure();
        if(count == 0 || maximum.getMeasure() < d.getMeasure())
        {
            maximum = d;
        }
        count++;
    }

    public Measurable getMaximum()
    {
        return maximum;
    }



    public double getAverage()
    {
        if(count == 0) return 0;
        else return sum / count;
    }
}
```

Measurable

```
public interface Measurable
{
    double getMeasure();
}
```

Comment: @KevinO  No they don't, because `sum` is a `double`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, @DawoodibnKareem, you're correct.

Comment: Maybe you should have a field that stores the last throw of the dice.  Make `cast` set the value of that field, and `getMeasure` return it.